# What is the type of "_id" field in Mongo database?

Tags: mongodb

Beginner in MongoDB.

- Created a local MongoDB server
- Used Mongoose to create a schema
- `_id: ObjectId("5b486d4057d0e42a3ca9c106")` was created by default.

What is the type of the `_id` property? On what query can I find/remove it? Can I create custom Id to save space in the database?
PS: Sorry If I am vague, I am still trying to understand how MongoDB works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The _id is the default key that is generated to uniquely identify each document in the collection.
The 12-byte ObjectId, which is a hexadecimal string value consists of:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

For further references, please go through the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Answer (score 5):

Although the previous accepted answer is correctly defining what an `ObjectId` is, the original question is asking "What is the type of the `_id` field in a MongoDB database?", and for that the previous answer is incomplete.

This field is mandatory, immutable and has uniqueness constraint in MongoDB collections. It is what would be the "primary key" in relational databases.

The `ObjectId` is only the *default type* for this field. In case you don't pass one when inserting a new document in the collection, MongoDB will automatically create one of these for you. This can be convenient because the `ObjectId`s are created in a way to avoid collisions and ensure an unique value is always assigned to the document. There are also other advantages of using `ObjectId` as the primary key, such as natural sorting by order of insertion, embedded timestamps, etc. See more [here](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/bson-data-types-objectid/) and [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field).

The important detail, however, is that you can also pass your own `_id` when inserting a document and it doesn't have to be of type `ObjectId`. In fact, according to MongoDB [document specification](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/), **it can be of any type except arrays**:

> The field name `_id` is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array. If the `_id` contains subfields, the subfield names cannot begin with a (`$`) symbol.

In the end, this is a DB design decision. Using automatic primary keys may not be exactly what you want. Actually, very often it is precisely what we *don't* want. If your record has a "natural" unique identifier, you should seriously consider using it instead of automatic ids.

The biggest flaw with using automatic `_id`s is that repeating an insert operation without a predefined `_id` will -- by default -- leave you with duplicated documents with the same contents in the collection, differing only by the `_id`. This can be avoided by creating other indices with uniqueness constraints, but most of the times deciding the `_id` in advance in the application realm is just more convenient.

Finally, to fully answer the question: yes, you can totally define other values for the `_id` field when creating a new document, but you can't remove or edit it later. To change the assigned `_id` you have to remove the old document and re-insert it with a different `_id`. Also, any disk space saving is likely to not be any relevant, as the `ObjectId`s themselves are already very small (only 12 bytes).

And one important final hint, learnt the hard way: if you use dictionaries/objects as `_id`, they are **order-sensitive**! It means that `{"foo": 1, "bar": 1}` *is different* from `{"bar": 1, "foo": 1}` also when querying. For programming languages that don't preserve key ordering in dicts/maps/objects, this can be a real pain and lead to "Heisenbugs". Keep that in mind and thank me later ;)